# Jquery hover event on multiple boxes

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$('.outerBox').hover(
  function() {
    $(this) > $('.innerBox').stop();
    $(this) > $('.innerBox').slideDown(750);
  },
  function() {
    $(this) > $('.innerBox').stop();
    $(this) > $('.innerBox').slideUp(750);
  }
);
```

```css
.outerBox {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
}
.innerBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerBox" id="outer1">
  <div class="innerBox" id="inner1"></div>
</div>
<div class="outerBox" id="outer2">
  <div class="innerBox" id="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

When I ran this with the id #outerBox and #innerBox and had only one  box on the page it worked great.
But I need this to be generic as I have multiple boxes ont hepage that need to run the same code.

When I use this, and I hover over any of the boxes, the slides happen on all of them.

How can I fix that?
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look right: `$(this) > $('.innerBox')` Better: `$('.innerBox', this)`

Comment: Use `$(this).find('.innerBox').…` (or `$('innerBox', this).…`) instead of `$(this) > $('.innerBox').…` (which makes no sense as neither `$(this)` nor `$('.innerBox').stop()` are numbers and could be compared with `>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Jquery [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of another selector.

This is because you want to "find" the value that's a child of `$(this)`

I would also use the power of jquery (which uses a [DRY technique](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/dont-repeat-yourself/)) to ensure you're using it to its maximum potential.

You'd end up with your script being similar to:

```
 $('.outerBox').hover(
      function() {
        $(this).find('.innerBox').stop().slideDown(750);
      },
      function() {
        $(this).find('.innerBox').stop().slideUp(750);
      }
    );
```

---

## Upon further refactoring, you could make it:

```
$('.outerBox').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.innerBox').stop().slideToggle(750);
});
```

**Notice** the shortened jquery?

---

```js
$('.outerBox').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.innerBox').stop().slideDown(750);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('.innerBox').stop().slideUp(750);
  }
);
```

```css
.outerBox {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  float: left;
  margin: 100px 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
}
.innerBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerBox" id="outer1">
  <div class="innerBox" id="inner1"></div>
</div>
<div class="outerBox" id="outer2">
  <div class="innerBox" id="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used jquery for a while, but never understood it, just copy/pasted.
Trying to learn it now and write my own code.
This was great

Comment: It takes a little bit getting used to, but after that, you'll find it a lot easier than vanilla js (for most things, that is)

Answer (score 2):

Use `find()` ... also you can short your function a little:

```
$('.outerBox').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.innerBox').stop().slideToggle(750);
});
```

```js
 $('.outerBox').hover(function () {
     $(this).find('.innerBox').stop().slideToggle(750);
 });
```

```css
 .outerBox {
     width: 350px;
     height: 350px;
     float: left;
     margin: 100px 100px;
     background-color: orange;
     position: relative;
 }
 .innerBox {
     position: absolute;
     width: 250px;
     height: 300px;
     bottom: 0px;
     margin: 0 50px;
     background-color: blue;
     display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerBox" id="outer1">
    <div class="innerBox" id="inner1"></div>
</div>
<div class="outerBox" id="outer2">
    <div class="innerBox" id="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```js
$('.outerBox').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).find('.innerBox').stop();
    $(this).find('.innerBox').slideDown(750);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find('.innerBox').stop();
    $(this).find('.innerBox').slideUp(750);
  }
});
```

```css
    .outerBox {
      width: 350px;
      height: 350px;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px 10px;
      background-color: orange;
      position: relative;
    }
    .innerBox {
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      height: 300px;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: 0 50px;
      background-color: blue;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerBox" id="outer1">
  <div class="innerBox" id="inner1"></div>
</div>
<div class="outerBox" id="outer2">
  <div class="innerBox" id="inner2"></div>
</div>
```